# php var inside database table

Tags: php, mysql

i want to know if is possible to insert a var inside php

mysql table `message` i inserted in column `header`

> "This is $Header From USA"

on my php page i have set

> $Header = 'Adam';

so what i want to do is if i call mysql and and get the row from message table

and echo it

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `message`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

$msg = $row['header']);

}

echo $msg;
```

it should echo

```
This is Adam From USA
```

is this possible ?
Thank you

Comment: Yes it is possible, but the variable would need to either be `parsed` with regex or `eval'd` which can lead to undesired vulnerabilities within your application. I suggest using a standardized template engine instead, such as `twig`.

Comment: thank you i will try to find something

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `message`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo 'This is '.$row['header'].' From USA';
}
```

Comment: i want to echo This is Adam From USA and right now its giving me This is $Header From USA

Comment: You can view the contents of a table message?

Comment: table message have id and header and on header i have inserted This is $Header From USA i guess the problem is mysql getting the $Header var like this \$Header backslash

Answer (score 0):

While the answers would be highly opinionated, a quick and dirty solution would be to use `str_replace` to parse out the desired replacement text.

```
$Header = 'Adam';
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `message`");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $msg = str_replace('$Header', $Header, $row['header']);
    //use single quotes to ensure the variable data is not used instead.
}

echo $msg;
```

This is under the impression that the variable names are known, instead of needing to be `eval'd`, which is discouraged.